# How can I test my android app on older versions?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, target

I have built an android app with targetSDK 15 and minSDK 3. How can I now test it on an older version? When I set the run configurations I only see my "android 4.0" AVD even though I have created AVD for older versions.

Is there any way to test my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test your app for various versions. follow these steps

- create all all versions of Android Virtual machines(avd) which you want to test
- run your app in all versions of avds which you have created by selecting android target

right click on the **project**-> **properties** -> **Android** -> set **target**

Enjoy the testing..

Answer (score 1):

Use an Emulator with an older Version.

The android level in project properties is the one which the app is build with. But in Manifest you can specifiy a minSDKVersion - that is the minimal Version for which your App will be available in Play store.
But with adb it is no problem to install it on devices or emulators which are not compatible to your current settings.

Answer (score 1):

Start AVD Manager from `Window -> AVD Manager.` Run any AVD you like first and then run the app.